# operation execution orders in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, column-alias

I'm trying to learn Postgresql with the help of this website https://www.postgresqltutorial.com.
But I'm confused in the order of operations.So I compared the order they say in this site with others, all are same to each other. In some queries the order of operations works as they mentioned like this one:

```
select customer_id C
from payment
where C > 10
```

and I got error that the alias (C) is not recognized as I expected because of the order of execution:

> FROM -> WHERE -> SELECT

The problem is here:

```
select 
customer_id C
from payment
where customer_id > 10
group by C
```

and it works fine without any error! Postgresql knows what **C** is inside the **group by** clause But the operation execution order here is not what it should be:

> FROM -> WHERE -> GROUP BY -> SELECT

So Postgresql knows what **C** is before **select** clause executes? how?

Comment: In theory the database _could_ allow to re-use the column alias in the WHERE clause. However the restriction that this isn't possible isn't really technically, but mandated by the SQL standard.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think you could construct interesting self-contradictory examples with aliases in the `WHERE` clause, but I have no example at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Order of logical execution of SELECT clauses is different for SQL Server than for PostgreSQL, Oracle and MySQL.
For SQL Server (described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN)):

```
FROM
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
SELECT
ORDER BY
```

For PostgreSQL, Oracle and MySQL the order is:

```
FROM
WHERE
SELECT
GROUP BY
HAVING
ORDER BY
```

It is listed for example [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/connect/post/on-rownum-and-limiting-results)